# Can I attach 2x4s to the studs in order to mount my TV?

Tags: drywall, walls, mounting

I have a tv wall mount that can be installed into studs 16" apart.  However id like to use it on a wall with studs 24" apart.

I'm thinking of drilling 2x4's into the studs and then attaching the mount to them.  Will this be a safe approach?

Comment: Sounds like a fine approach. Just use lag bolts or at least wood screws. Drywall screws aren't meant to carry much of a load at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually one of the most often recommended approaches to solving this problem. If you're up for a bit of drywall work. You could cut open the wall a bit, and install the 2x4s between the studs.

For a quick fix, bolting 2x4s to the studs on the outside of the wall should work just fine. If you paint the 2x4s the same color as the wall, it might help to blend them in a bit.

Another option is to try and find a mount that accommodates 24" stud spacing, though this may not be an option if you already have a mount you want to use.

Comment: Depending on the weight of the TV, you might also be able to use 1-by stock (eg, a 1x8) or even a piece of plywood on the surface. Be sure to use lag bolts still. Keep in mind that the further the TV is away from the wall, the more force it will have on the attachment -- mostly a concern if the mount is articulated. I have a couple computer monitors at home on articulated arms attached to 1-by stock on the outside of the drywall, but if I was doing say, a 50" TV on an articulated arm, I'd use a 2x4 or 2x6.  Or just get a mount that was 24"+ wide.